# Creating a variable-sized justified text block

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I need to create a block of text that looks like this:

[image: text block]

Is there a term for this kind of variable-sized justified text? Is there a JavaScript library to size this correctly, or is it possible in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS alone won't cater for this. You're after Fittext.js: http://fittextjs.com/